# The construction of Rooty helix, code explanation

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, counters, loops, for-loop

Could someone please explain some parts of this code? I'm newbie on LaTeX and could not understand some parts.

What does this `\foreach \y in {86,38,15}` means?

Could you explain with details what is this loop doing 
`\foreach \x in {1,...,\y}{ 
... %here the dots represent all the code included in the main code below
}`

?

I would really appreciate any help you're willing to provide. Thank you.

```
% Rooty helix
% Author: Felix Lindemann


\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\xdefinecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{175, 193, 36}
\newcounter{cntShader}
\newcounter{cntRoot}
\setcounter{cntShader}{20}
\def\couleur{darkgreen}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \y in {86,38,15}{
        \setcounter{cntShader}{1}
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (0:1);
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\y}{%
            \coordinate (c) at ($ (b)!1cm!270:(a) $);
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                \draw[fill=\couleur!\thecntShader] (a)--(b)--(c)--cycle;
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            \setcounter{cntRoot}{\x}
            \addtocounter{cntRoot}{1}
            \node[fill=white,draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (c)
                {$\sqrt{\thecntRoot}$};
            \coordinate (b) at (c);
            \pgfmathsetcounter{cntShader}{\thecntShader+4}
            \setcounter{cntShader}{\thecntShader}
       }
    }
    \node[fill=white,draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (0:1) {$\sqrt{1}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! These are so-called loops, which allow you to repeat stuff with different parameters. They are explained at great length in the pgfmanual on p. 901. The outer loop `\foreach \y in {86,38,15}` sets the maximal value for `\x` in the inner loop `\foreach \x in {1,...,\y}`.

Comment: @marmot Oh ok thank you. I'll check it. If the outer loop sets the maximal value for `\x` then that value would be 86?

Comment: Yes, there is a first loop up to 86, then to 38 and then to 15. Two things: could you please provide us with the source of the code? And I think at this point it is not very clear how to give an official answer to your question. (IMHO just copying from the manual is not necessarily a good answer.) Do you want someone to simplify this code?

Comment: @marmot :) I found it here https://gist.github.com/felixlindemann/6229067 . With simplifying do you mean to make it more easy to understand?

Comment: @marmot What does this means `\coordinate (c) at ($ (b)!1cm!270:(a) $);` I know that the main idea is (angle:length) but what kind of angle is `(b)!1cm!270` ?

Comment: This is explained on p. 144 of the pgfmanual, 13.5.4 The Syntax of Distance Modifiers. I guess I will add an alternative code. Is there any relation between the number and the radius?

Comment: @marmot Oh ok thanks! Which number and radius?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proposal to rewrite the code in such a way that it is more understandable. Whether or not it is really more understandable will probably depend on who is looking at it. Anyway, instead of having two loops this code has one. It use `decorations.marking` (which of course also uses a loop internally) to place the nodes. From how I interpret your code the calc arithmetics is used to have approximately equal distances between the circles, but `decorations.markings` gives you that for free. The shadings are done on the background layer as in the above code, but in a single loop. In particular, if you ever want to have a different maximal value, or a different spiral, I claim that the following will be easier to adjust.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\xdefinecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{175, 193, 36}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1/86 with {%
    \node[fill=white,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] 
    (n-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}){%
    $\sqrt{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}}$};}}] 
    plot[variable=\x,domain=45:945,samples=86]
    (\x:{0.5+pow(\x/66,4/5)});     
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX,evaluate=\X as \Y using
    {int(3*\X+255-3*87)}] in {87,86,...,1}
    {\ifnum\X=87
    \else
     \draw[fill=darkgreen!\Y] (n-\LastX.center) -- (n-\X.center) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \fi}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to do everything at once, i.e. effectively with one loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\xdefinecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{175, 193, 36}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xmax}{87}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xnmax}{\xmax-1}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1/\xnmax with {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{1+\xmax-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myy}{\myx+1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myz}{3*\myx+255-3*\xmax}
    \node[fill=white,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] 
    (n-\myx){%
    $\sqrt{\myx}$};
    \ifnum\myx=\xmax
    \else
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
     \draw[fill=darkgreen!\myz] (n-\myx.center) -- (n-\myy.center) -- (O) -- cycle;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \fi
    }}] 
    plot[variable=\x,domain=930:0,samples=\xmax]
    (\x:{0.5+pow(\x/66,4/5)+ifthenelse(\x<0.1,0.3,0)});     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to draw more or less roots, you need to change `\xmax` and also adjust the domain, i.e. replace `domain=930:0` by something else. Since the radius grows, the relation between the upper bound of the domain (`930` in the present example) and `\xmax` is not linear. Rather, there is an empirical law (which I "derived" by integrating the arc length and fitting a function which says that the upper bound of the domain goes like `pow(\xmax/87,0.65)*930`, where `\xmax` is the largest number, i.e. 87 in the examples above.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\xdefinecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{175, 193, 36}
\foreach \X in {10,15,...,100}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare
function={Rad(\x)=1+pow(\x/66,4/5)+ifthenelse(\x<1,0.3,0);}]
\path[use as bounding box] (-12,-10.5) rectangle (12,9.5);
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xmax}{\X}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xnmax}{\xmax-1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Xmax}{pow(\xmax/87,0.65)*930}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1/\xnmax with {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{1+\xmax-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myy}{\myx+1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myz}{3*\myx+255-3*\xmax}
    \node[fill=white,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] 
    (n-\myx){%
    $\sqrt{\myx}$};
    \ifnum\myx=\xmax
    \else
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
     \draw[fill=darkgreen!\myz] (n-\myx.center) -- (n-\myy.center) -- (O) -- cycle;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \fi
    }}] 
    plot[variable=\x,domain=\Xmax:0,samples=\xmax]
    (\x:{Rad(\x)});     
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand nothing :O .All the new commands included are in the pgfmanual right?

Comment: @user178403 Yes, I am using mainly `decorations.markings`, which is explained in section 48.5 Arbitrary Markings and loops, which are explained at great length in the pgfmanual on p. 901.

Comment: alright, I'll read about it

Comment: Notice there is a slight difference with your helix and mine because mine has the sqrt{1} circle on the X axe and your sqrt{1} circle is at 45 degrees on the XY plane.

Comment: @user178403 all you need to do is to change `domain=45:945` to `domain=0:945` or `domain=0:900`. (One can shorten the code further. This is a compromise between being explicit and and avoiding hard coded numbers like `86,38,15` and gimmicks (sorry for the wording!) like `\pgfmathsetcounter{cntShader}{\thecntShader+4}
            \setcounter{cntShader}{\thecntShader}`, where `\addtocounter{cntShader}{4}` does the same and is shorter and which can be avoided altogether if you condense the code to one loop.)

Comment: Someday I'll understand your code ;) . Anyway thanks for your help.